# Fetch NFT onchain data as JSON

Tags: nft, fetch, solscan, json

I was wondering if, apart from the magic eden API, if it was possible to directly fetch on-chain NFT collection data(in JSON) with javascript? Or does that have to be done via web scraping?

Answer (score 1):

Sure can! But the NFT metadata is stored off-chain actually (Arweave, NFT storage etc...) the on-chain data has the URI that holds the NFT metadata.

You can try the [metaplex findByMint method](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#findByMint), just give it a mint Address and it'll returns an Nft object.

`const nft = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint({ mintAddress }).run();`

Also see the [Solana Cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/nfts.html#how-to-get-nft-metadata) for a more complete example.

P.S. There's also 3rd party API's from Quicknode and Moralis you could try.